# При добавлении новой записи в базу код цикла дублируется

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Вот это не выводится теперь

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table-get-kre">
                    <tr class="info">
                      <th>Опис</th>
                      <th style="text-align: center;">ГРН</th>
                      <th style="text-align: center;">PLN</th>
                      <th style="text-align: center;">EUR</th>
                      <th style="text-align: center;">USD</th>
                      <th style="text-align: center;">Завешення кредитів</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- вивести тут -->


                    <!-- вивести тут -->
                  </table>
```

---

Вот структура таблицы

[image: Ось структура таблиці]

Если я закомментирую `echo json_encode($output);` в php файле, то стиль таблицы верхней части нормально работает, вот скрин:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0N_1p6wnchMX0h4cHRGNW9pYTg

Comment: Ответ сервера у вас возвращает все записи, в итоге у вас старые строки из таблицы остаются и после них добавляются новые. Либо заменить метод вставки (`append` -> `html`), либо в ответ присылайте только массив с новой записью, а не всеми.

Comment: если меняю append -> html то виводитса просто одна запись ((  а как присилать только новие записи?

Comment: сейчас напишу в ответе

Comment: как вариант можно хранить в каком то массиве id записей, которые вывелись, и пропускать их при дальнейших рендерах

Comment: Что касается "как прислать только новые" - вы же как-то создаете новую запись - те же данные только в формате массива и отдавайте обратно, если создание новой записи в БД прошло успешно.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала создать переменную `html`, потом в неё складируем наши строки, после цикла вставляем в table.

```js
function getTableKredit() {
  var id;
  $.ajax({
    url:"credit-table.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { 
      let html = '';
      const $table = $('table'),
        $head = $table.find('tr.info').clone();
      
      for(let item of data) {
        html += '' +
        '<tr>' +
          '<td style="text-align: left;">' + item.description + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + item.grn + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + item.pln + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + item.eur + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + item.usd + '</td>' +
          '<td><a href="?kredit=1&id=' + item.id + '" class="delete-kredit">Видалити кредит</a></td>' +
        '</tr>';
      }
      
      $table.html(html).prepend($head);
    }
  });
}
```

**P.S.** Хотя лучше конечно отдавать обратно данные только о новой записи и их через `append` вставлять.

Comment: вставил, но теперь ничего не виводитса (

Comment: @Alex Kizyma, пардон, поправил

Comment: всеровно не виводитса ничего (((

Comment: @Alex Kizyma, + забыл =/ поправил

Comment: Вивелось но тепрь не виводитса верхняя часть таблици что прописана html

Comment: @Alex Kizyma, а, у вас в таблице есть элементы которые надо оставить ... ну тогда этот вариант я бы исключил, можно и так сделать не перезаписывая просто нужные строки, но это уже костыль, проще возвращать одну строку и вставлять в конец таблицы.

Comment: @Alex Kizyma, если решите все же этот вариант оставить, то обновил, что бы "шапка" не затиралась.

Comment: Все роботает только не понимаю почему стили Bootstrapa таблици пропали  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0N_1p6wnchMQmpQREtMZ3ZmZXc

Comment: @Alex Kizyma, скиньте скрин разметки таблицы до того, как в неё что-то добавляется, просто в примере вашей разметки нет tbody, thead, я на них и не рассчитывал, а на сколько я понимаю бутстрап через них свой каскад строит.